# How to perform click on button of ListView element in Android

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I have listView and each element contains 1 button
[image]

When user presses some element of ListView (but not button) it works correctly and android shows toast: "Not button clicked, $position works correctly"

But I also need to make toast (and get position of button) when button is clicked in specific listView element. I tried to use `view.imageViewButton.setOnClickListener` inside of `listV.setOnItemClickListener` but in this scenario button worked only after I clicked a blank space to the left of the button.

```
listV.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
  //I tried you use comented line to solwe my problem
  //view.imageViewButton.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "button $position is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
  Toast.makeText(this, "not button clicked, works correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

How should I do to activate buttons when `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`  starts?

My kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var db = DataBaseHelper(this)
    var cursor = db.returnLines()

    listV.adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.view_holder,
        cursor,
        arrayOf("imia"),
        intArrayOf(R.id.listNameView),
        0)

    listV.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

      //I tried you use comented line to solwe my problem
      //view.imageViewButton.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "button $position is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
      Toast.makeText(this, "not button clicked, $position works correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend SimpleCursorAdapter to set click listener to specific view

```
class CustomAdapter(context: Context?, layout: Int, c: Cursor?, from: Array<out String>?, to: IntArray?) : SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, from, to) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent).apply {
            if (convertView == null) { // This means newView()
                findViewById<View>(R.id.image_view).setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "image view clicked pos=$position")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I recommend you to use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

ListView is old-fashioned and deprecated to use

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, It was very helpful!

Comment: if (convertView == null) { // This means newView() - I tried to understand this line of code but I do not understand why do wee need to use it... Why do we need it? And also, what if I need to start activity on pressing R.id.image_view button? I can make intent object inside of function getView() in CustomAdapter class but I do not able to perform startActivity() inside getView(). What should I do to startActivity after pressing R.id.image_view? I want to parse clicked item position to that activity by using intent.putExtra("pos", position)

Comment: I need details. How is not able to invoke startActivity inside getView()? Does it cause fatal exception?

Comment: getView() creates view through newView() if there is no view. If there is view created it re-uses view through bindView().

Comment: In a nutshell, set click listener when the target view is created (only once)

Comment: Somehow I find solution but it looks like very weird for me because I need to use startActivity(context, intent, null) instead of startActivity(intent)... Here is photo of code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wJfBzzkm7Zr3lHgxms9M7P1UTsEOAqLh   Is it normal way to do? problem with finish() apeared (you can see it on screenshoot). I suppose I did something wrong... Could I get position of clicked button inside of my MainActivity? Sorry for such probably stupped questions, I am very new in programming and this is my third app I create mysell (not by tutorial), hope you understand :(...

Comment: Activity instance is needed to perform `startActivity` and `finish`.
You have to deliver activity instance from activity to adapter you created.